# Get data from SAP HANA to Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, hana

I have a requirement to get data to Salesforce from the Web portal developed with Open UI5 and SAP HANA. The data has to be moved to Salesforce at each and every insert of a records happening in Open UI5 portal. Again the record is processes at Salesforce and the updated records has to be moved to SAP HANA.

Please let me know is that possible and what are the necessary steps I need to follow, and how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will likely want to use replication from your Salesforce system to your HANA system.  Depending on your architectural needs, you should look at:

[SAP Landscape Transformation (SLT)](http://scn.sap.com/community/saplt) which is a trigger based approach.

[SAP Replication Server (SRS)](http://scn.sap.com/community/sap-replication-server) which is a log based approach.

In the SAP Community Network, look at Presentations and Related Resources on the left column to find most of the documentation you will need.

Both have different advantages, and disadvantages, so you should read up on them to decide which will better suit your needs.

Comment: @nirmal10 Was this answer helpful? In that case, consider to upvote/accept this answer.